# How to detect IE/Edge using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to use javascript to apply a certain style to the pages based on which browser the user is using. I can detect all of the browsers except for IE/Edge. In my code snippet I am just trying to detect IE/Edge and apply the style.

Here is my code:

```
var bodyStyle = document.querySelector("#bodyArea");
if((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Edge") != -1 ) || (!!document.documentMode == true ))
{
    alert("asdf");
    bodyStyle.style.paddingTop = "500px";
}
else
{
    bodyStyle.style.paddingTop = "300px";
}
```

When I put an alert in the else section it gives me an alert, but it doesn't work on the if part. So I think my problem is occurring when I try to detect IE/Edge. Or if it lay elsewhere, let me know. If anyone has any feedback, it will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry. Have to ask... Why are you trying to revise the page just for IE & Edge users?

Comment: Please use css for this! Your life will change: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32940965/how-to-target-microsoft-edge-with-css

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I am doing so because I applied for an internship, and I am trying to make everything function/appear correctly across all the browsers, but IE/Edge won't work with any of my code:'( If it was just for my own use or whatever, I wouldn't really care about IE/Edge users haha

Comment: @Austin If the differences are drastic, check that the browser is using [standards mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325.aspx) vs. a [legacy document mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915.aspx) when rendering the page. If it's an intranet site, IE/Edge may default to a compatibility view. The use of [Enterprise Mode](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt270205.aspx) can also set this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I detect IE and Edge browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33152523/how-do-i-detect-ie-and-edge-browser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this custom `script` to detect IE/Edge:

```
if (/MSIE 10/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
   // this is internet explorer 10
   window.alert('isIE10');
}

if(/MSIE 9/i.test(navigator.userAgent) || /rv:11.0/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
    // this is internet explorer 9 and 11
    window.location = 'pages/core/ie.htm';
}

if (/Edge\/12./i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
   // this is Microsoft Edge
   window.alert('Microsoft Edge');
}
```

Check out this page for the latest IE and Edge user agent strings: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh869301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I believe this will not work when the user agent is spoofed but should be fine in general.

Comment: Correct, op just wants to detect IE/edge with JS.

Comment: IMO having to detect the browser in JS means that their is a bigger problem somewhere. In OP's use case, there is absolutely no need of client script detection of the browser. Presentation should always be worked in presentation code, not in JS.

Comment: @Frederik.L I just came to that conclusion, about 5 mins ago, so I started to do some digging, and I think that my script file isn't linking to my html in IE/Edge or something, because it won't even give me a simple alert(), so I have no idea what is wrong at this point :|

Comment: Do you have your script file correctly called in your HTML file?

Comment: @Gothburz The script file will run in chrome and other browsers, but it isn't running in Edge, I tried using <script></script> in the actual html file and it worked in Edge, it just isn't linking to my .js file for some reason. This is my code to link it `<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>`

Comment: And your JS file is in the root directory and not in its own folder?

Comment: @Gothburz Yeah it is, all of my files for this site are just in the same folder.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32617995/unable-to-run-javascript-in-external-file-in-microsoft-edge-browser seems you're not the only one.

Comment: @Gothburz I just got done reading that post lol. Ughhh I am ready to send my project, but IE/Edge sucks!! Well thanks for your help! I appreciate it! I guess I will just send it.

Comment: I'll keep my eyes open and see if I can find a solution as well.

Comment: @Gothburz I found this. If it can be of any help. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/769317b9-318c-40b2-ba4f-7a9d27265e71/microsoft-edge-sandboxing-of-external-javascript-code-breaks-prototypejs?forum=ieitprocurrentver. It seems that Edge is treating external js differently.

Comment: @Frederik.L I was messing around with positioning of my script file call, It doesn't seem to work when I link to it in the <head></head> it doesn't work, but I put the link at the bottom of the <body></body> and now it works fine, it just breaks my html5 local storage that I have intact. So I am close